# ffmpeg Music Player

Tags: c, ffmpeg

I'm interested in writing a simple music player in C using ffmpeg, but the documentation at the ffmpeg site is pretty barebones and searches for tutorials didn't really turn up anything. Most of the tutorials I've seen are related to writing video players.

Does anyone know of any good resources for learning how to use ffmpeg? Considering I just want to write a simple music player with support for a broad range of formats and codecs, is ffmpeg too heavyweight for a project of this scope? If so, what should I be using?

Thanks!

Comment: For future reference with respect to ffmpeg: You may find it useful to visit forums such as doom9: http://forum.doom9.org. You can usually ask the actually developers here, or on IRC, since they don't really visit this site that much IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

FFMPEG is good but is  a bit overkill and heavyweight I think. There are lots of features and stuff you wont need. It makes your part of the coding more complicated than necessary. FFMPEG is more suitable for video player.

I think you should check out audio library called "*BASS*". It is lightweight and its C API implementation is very clear and easy to use. By default it supports **MP3, MP2, MP1, OGG, WAV, AIFF** audio formats and **XM, IT, S3M, MOD, MTM, UMX** module formats.

It has also pretty good addon (plugin) support so  you can easily expand the audio support as you wish. There are already plugins for **WMA, FLAC, MIDI** and other popular formats. Bassmod can be used for free if your product is not commercial. If you want to use it in commercial product(s), you have to buy a license for it.

Btw, there are already few music players using this library (like freeware player called "*Billy*").

Here is the link to the homepage: **[http://www.un4seen.com](http://www.un4seen.com/)**

There is also library called "*FMOD*" which is worth checking. Lots of games and commercial products are using this effective library. It is primarily focused to audio processing (effects) and samples. Personally I think that *BASS* is more suitable for building a compact and lightweight music player.